# Showing Linear Independence $\{1,\sin x,\cos x\}$

Tags: linear-algebra, trigonometry

I don't know how to show that $a+b\sin(x)+c\cos(x)=0$ has no solutions...

How should I go about doing this? Is the only way using the $\sin^2+\cos^2=1$ identity and substituting that?

Comment: It is imprecise (and false) to say that $a + b \sin(x) + c \sin(x) = 0$ has no solutions. First, do you mean for $a,b,c$, or for $x$? Second, it does have a solution: $a=b=c=0$. You could express this more accurately as "the only $a,b,c$ for which $a + b \sin(x) + c \sin(x) = 0$ holds for all $x \in \mathbb R$ are $a=b=c=0$". The important part here is "for all $x \in \mathbb R$", whence the technique in the answer below of substituting values of $x$.

Comment: Thank you @Théophile for these clarifications. I admit I was a bit rushed when I was typing this. Although you might already noticed this, but originally I was asking this for the intent of showing the linear independence. Hence, I meant to say "has no non-trivial solutions."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Substitute *values* of $x$ in the supposed identity $a+b\sin x +c\cos x=0$.  Use for example $x=0$, $x=\pi/2$, $x=-\pi/2$.  Then conclude that $a=b=c=0$.

The above is probably the simplest approach, and works nicely in other situations.  But other ideas can be brought to bear on the problem. For example, if $a+b\sin x+c\cos x$ is identically $0$, then, by differentiating, we can conclude that $b\cos x-c\sin x$ is identically $0$. Put $x=0$. We conclude that $b=0$. Differentiate again, set $x=0$. We conclude that $c=0$. Then looking back at $a+b\sin x +c\cos x$, we conclude that $a=0$.

Comment: Ok. This implies that $a,b,c= 0$. the only case where we have solution.